# sql select same column multiple times (using online oracle explorer)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have exploratory access to a db using the online explorer(oracle), only 1000 records are returned at a time.

Thus, I need to make sure that the data returned contains a sufficient subset

as a basic example, tableA with columns

```
id chartid
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    d
2    b


select id
from tableA
where chartid in (a,d)
  and chartid in (b)
  and chartid in (c)
```

should return

```
id
1
```

I want to make sure that the ids I then run my query on contain enough of the needed data(otherwise, its sparse)

--thankyou
how is this done in general?
is this a limitation of the explorer/online interface ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to approach these using `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from TableA
group by id
having sum(case when chartid in ('a', 'd') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when chartid in ('b') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when chartid in ('c') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows, for a given `id`, that match each condition.  The `> 0` guarantees that at least one row exists that meets each of the conditions.

EDIT:

I'm not actually sure *what* your conditions are, because it is not meeting all three that you meet.  If you want to meet just one of them, them use `or`.  If you want two out of the three, then use:

```
having (max(case when chartid in ('a', 'd') then 1 else 0 end) +
        max(case when chartid in ('b') then 1 else 0 end) +
        max(case when chartid in ('c') then 1 else 0 end)
       ) >= 2;
```

Comment: i am going to check this as the answer --thankyou  ; {however for my purposes it is not working do to the limitations of the provider, i am resorting to simpler queries over subsequent chartids of interest}

Answer (score 1):

The answer Gordon Linoff provided is probably the best, but just for reference a general approach to this kind problem would be to break it down into smaller parts (ie form multiple sets) and then join them. Something looking like this:

```
select t1.id 
from tableA t1 
inner join tableA t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join tableA t3 on t1.id = t3.id
where 
  t1.chartid in ('a','d')  
  and t2.chartid = 'b'
  and t3.chartid = 'c'
```

This query would form three distinct sets and then return the intersect of them. At least for me, thinking in terms of sets often is helpful when doing relational database queries (although the solution might not be the most efficient).

[Sample SQL Fiddle with both queries](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfd75/4).

Comment: hi, thanks ive tried both yours and gordon linoffs approachds.  the query is taking a long time to run.. i tried to use 'explain plan for' but that gives a right parenthesis error..  (ill try another location.. maybe slow connection here.. ill mark you answer later this evening if it works)